# function() missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The problem shows in line 90.

I think the main problem is with the dataframe. So after calculating values from `function` I return a data frame. the function is used in a for loop to generate different lines such as this given below.

Representative plot:
I have been trying a few clues but it is still not working

![enter image description here][1]

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#tst=529
#temp=524
#dtube=0.41

def function(ConstantA,ConstantB,tst,temp,dtube):
# variables and constants
    k0 = 38.9
    e = 90000
    lambd=-328200
    dp=0.003;roecat= 1670; porosity=0.4; cpa=95.2; cpb=32; cpc= 102.81;cpc= 71; ma=28;mb=32;mc=44;md=16; viscosity=0.25e-4;tst=tst;
    dtube=dtube;ntube=25000; ltube= 9.8288; dw=1;wplot=0; yar=0;ybr=0;np=0;pi=3.1416; areacstube= pi * (dtube ** 2) / 4; wmaxtube=ltube * areacstube * roecat;wmax=wmaxtube * ntube;
    # Initial conditions
    w=0; fc=0; fa0=0.8125; fb0=0.26;fd0=2.175;fr=0;temp=temp; p=17; fain=fr * yar+fa0; fbin=fr * ybr+fb0;fdin=fd0;
```

Comment: I wonder if you can try `function(*row)`. currently, looks like you’re missing a few arguments in the function call.

Comment: That worked Can you please explain a little?

Comment: The function requires more than one positional argument currently. The star `*` operator unpacks the input sequence, so for example `function(*[1, 2, 3])`, which would otherwise be one argument without the *, becomes `function(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Can you please also help with labeling the data? How can I modify the axis?

Comment: that likely seems a different question altogether. I’d suggest opening up a new question on SO - once you’ve done a quick Google search of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `function(row)`, which only includes one argument of the required 5 (which are `ConstantA,ConstantB,tst,temp,dtube`).

If you would like to unpack each item in the row so that if corresponds to each argument, you can do `function(*row)` instead.